# Itertools for * arguments

Tags: python

I want to have a function to generate cross product of arbitrary number of arrays.

```
# Code to generate cross product of 3 arrays
M = [1, 1]
N = [2, 3]
K = [4, 5]
for M, N, K in itertools.product(M, N, K)
```

If I want to introduce a function using *, what is a good way to achieve that?

I tried the following code, but ended with an error: `"TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"`

```
# def cross_product(*inputs):
      return itertools.product(inputs)

cross_product(M, N, K)
```

Comment: Just unpack them `return itertools.product(*inputs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just use unpacking without a helper function:

```
import itertools

L = [[1, 1],
     [2, 3],
     [4, 5]]

for x in itertools.product(*L):
    print(x)
```